# Git bash-completion with filename support?

Tags: git, bash, bash-completion

is there a bash-completion script that supports filename completion? I use mostly mercurial and there I can type:

```
hg diff test/test_<tab>
```

and it will show/complete all modified test files. It works for most subcommands, i.e. `hg add <tab><tab>` will only list untracked files. It is really handy.

The bash script from git contrib seams to not support this. Are there any alternatives, or how do you work with git on the command line?

**Edit 2015**

`git-completion.bash` supports full filename completion since [~1.8.2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fea16b47b603e7e4fa7fca198bd49229c0e5da3d)

Comment: I normally use `git status` first, and then know what to type for `git diff`. (But most often I'm using `gitk` for seeing differences.)

Comment: Note: With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the filename completion will be faster. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124294/6309).

Answer (score 13):

So, let's see how the Mercurial bash completion script does this.

This is the [important part](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/bf85c2639700/contrib/bash_completion#l83):

```
_hg_status()
{
    local files="$(_hg_cmd status -n$1 .)"
    local IFS=$'\n'
    COMPREPLY=(${COMPREPLY[@]:-} $(compgen -W '$files' -- "$cur"))
}
```

It gets called [here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/bf85c2639700/contrib/bash_completion#l208):

```
_hg_command_specific()
{
    case "$cmd" in 
    [...]
    diff)
        _hg_status "mar"
    ;;
    [...]
    esac
    return 0
}
```

Thus, it is simply a call of `hg status -nmar`, and using the output as a list of files for completion.

I think it would not be too hard to patch something similar into the [git completion script](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob/HEAD:/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) - we would have to modify `__git_diff` here to not do a plain filename + branch completion, but calling `git status` instead.

---

The commands

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^.[^ ?]' | cut -b 4-
```

(for `git diff --cached`) and

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^[^ ?]' | cut -b 4-
```

(for `git diff`) seem to output the right thing (if there are no renames).

They both are not useful when diffing to anything other than HEAD, though.

A more general way would be to use

```
git diff --relative --name-only [--cached] [commit1] [commit2]]
```

where `commit1` and `commit2` (and maybe `--cached`) come from the already given diff command line.

---

I implemented the idea outlined above in bash, and patched into `git-completion.bash`. If you don't want to change your `git-completion.bash`, add these two functions to some bash file and source it after the original `git-completion.bash`. It should now work with commands like

```
git diff -- <tab>
git diff --cached -- <tab>
git diff HEAD^^ -- <tab>
git diff origin/master master -- <tab>
```

I [submitted this](https://lore.kernel.org/git/4DD30F87.2000807@gmx.de/t/#u) as a patch to the git mailing list, let's see what results from this. (I'll update this answer as I get feedback there.)

```
# Completion for the file argument for git diff.
# It completes only files actually changed. This might be useful
# as completion for other commands as well.
#
# The idea comes from the bash completion for Mercurial (hg),
# which does something similar (but more simple, only difference of
# working directory to HEAD and/or index, if I understand right).
# It (the idea) was brought to us by the question
#      http://stackoverflow.com/q/6034472/600500
#  from "olt".
__git_complete_changed_files()
{
  #
  # We use "git diff --name-only --relative" to generate the list,
  # but this needs the same --cached and <commit> arguments as the
  # command line being constructed.
  #


    # first grab arguments like --cached and any commit arguments.

    local -a args=()
    local finish=false

    for (( i=1 ; i < cword ; i++)) do
    local current_arg=${words[$i]}
    #  echo checking $current_arg >&2
       case $current_arg in
           --cached)
               args+=( $current_arg )
               ;;
           --)
               # finish parsing arguments, the rest are file names
               break
               ;;
           -*)
               # other options are ignored
               ;;
           *)
               if git cat-file -e $current_arg 2> /dev/null
               then
                   case $( git cat-file -t $current_arg ) in
                       commit|tag)
                       # commits and tags are added to the command line.
                           args+=( $current_arg )
                           # echo adding $current_arg >&2
                           ;;
                       *)
                   esac
               fi
               ;;
       esac
    done

    # now we can call `git diff`

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen \
        -W "$( git diff --name-only --relative "${args[@]}" -- )" -- $cur ) )
}

_git_diff ()
{
    if __git_has_doubledash
    then
        # complete for the file part: only changed files
        __git_complete_changed_files
    else
    case "$cur" in
    --*)
        __gitcomp "--cached --staged --pickaxe-all --pickaxe-regex
            --base --ours --theirs --no-index
            $__git_diff_common_options
            "
        return
        ;;
    esac
    __git_complete_revlist_file
    fi
}
```

---

**Update:** Looks like this patch is not wanted in this form, as the current way to complete files is more useful for people which want to check whether there are changes in some subdirectory (e.g. completing when the diff output could be empty). It might be accepted if linked to some configuration variable (with the default being the current behavior). Also, the indenting should be adapted to the standard (see the answer from [Junio C Hamano](https://lore.kernel.org/git/7v8vu4efvj.fsf@alter.siamese.dyndns.org/)).

I might take another go on it, but can't guarantee this for the near future. If someone else want to do, feel free to take my code, change it and submit it again.

Answer (score 3):

This solves the `git diff <tab>` problem for me, put the following in **.bashrc**:

```
alias gid='git diff'
__gdiff () {
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts=$(git status --porcelain | grep '^.[^ ?]' | cut -b 4-)

    case "${prev}" in
        gid)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
            ;;
    esac
}
complete -F __gdiff gid
```

And then do `gid <tab>` instead of `git diff <tab>`. It may be simplified, but seems to work well as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Not really your desired answer but I wanted to let you know that soon fish (friendly interactive shell) will give you git filename completion support out of the box. It is currently in master with a 2.3.0 release coming soon.

https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/901
https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/2364
https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/commit/c5c59d4acb00674bc37198468b5978f69484c628

If you have a status like this:

```
$ git status
modified: ../README.md
$ git add <tab>
:/README.md
```

[image]

You can also just type `README` and hit tab and it will insert it for you if it is the only match. Friggin nice!

Comment: See my 2015 update in the post: "git-completion.bash supports full filename completion since ~1.8.2"

Answer (score 0):

Since 2011, as the OP comments, Git supports full filename completion since ~1.8.2.

But with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the shell completion (in `contrib/`) that gives list of paths have been optimized somewhat.

See [commit 78a2d21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78a2d2123103f4524bfce30511e0a8b2d27d3502) (04 Apr 2018) by [Clemens Buchacher (`drizzd`)](https://github.com/drizzd).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3a940e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a940e90d505a3f2ea20e5ebc5b7acad131ad204), 25 Apr 2018)</sup>

> ### `completion`: improve `ls-files` filter performance

> From the output of `ls-files`, we remove all but the leftmost path
> component and then we eliminate duplicates. We do this in a `while` loop,
> which is a performance bottleneck when the number of iterations is large
> (e.g. for 60000 files in `linux.git`).
>
> ```
> $ COMP_WORDS=(git status -- ar) COMP_CWORD=3; time _git
>
> real    0m11.876s
> user    0m4.685s
> sys     0m6.808s
> ```
>
> Replacing the loop with the cut command improves performance
> significantly:
>
> ```
> $ COMP_WORDS=(git status -- ar) COMP_CWORD=3; time _git
>
> real    0m1.372s
> user    0m0.263s
> sys     0m0.167s
> ```
>
> The measurements were done with Msys2 bash, which is used by Git for
> Windows.
>
> When filtering the `ls-files` output we take care not to touch absolute
> paths. This is redundant, because `ls-files` will never output absolute
> paths. Remove the unnecessary operations.
>
> The issue was originally reported [Git for Windows issue 1533](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1533).

---

The directory traversal code had redundant recursive calls which made its performance characteristics exponential with respect to the depth of the tree, which was corrected with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020).

See [commit c0af173](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0af173a136785b3cfad4bd414b2fb10a130760a), [commit 95c11ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c11ecc73f286e0a95d9591ae98f1221efe4633), [commit 7f45ab2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f45ab2dca04c5b76958843120c6bd6d3a033043), [commit 1684644](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1684644489fbd76d01fe3bb53c65df6856fd00c5), [commit 8d92fb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d92fb292706fd8d13cfe55353b2ec9345153a3e), [commit 2df179d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2df179d3dfeb431cc3030ac44e79b136debf1fd9), [commit 0126d14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0126d1415a63ed24764f5f87a10929bc6222bddd), [commit cd129ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd129eed986588907d1f1bd7d478a8d4f6d1dc1c), [commit 446f46d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/446f46d8c7ea3b91f7afe4c5a46b5cd20cc40196), [commit 7260c7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7260c7b66e83ef2fa02c5a0440623cc6c99b73a3), [commit ce5c61a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce5c61a3f52b48497898dbe4e535e725b1c45794) (01 Apr 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 0bbd0e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bbd0e8b5233b7cf66b846d4c1825a530d8402bd) (01 Apr 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6eacc39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6eacc39b6d2508b6a7522902330c29714c99f5f2), 29 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0af173a136785b3cfad4bd414b2fb10a130760a): fix '`git add`' on paths under an untracked directory
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> As reported on the git mailing list, since git-2.25,
>
> ```
> git add untracked-dir/
> ```
>
> has been tab completing to
>
> ```
> git add untracked-dir/./
> ```
>
> The cause for this was that with [commit b9670c1f5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9670c1f5e6b98837c489a03ac0d343d30e08505) ("`dir`: fix checks on common prefix directory", 2019-12-19, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2189a721cc08b78b63853b8aa825dc828e835cf)),
>
> ```
> git ls-files -o --directory untracked-dir/
> ```
>
> (or the equivalent `git -C untracked-dir ls-files -o --directory`) began reporting
>
> ```
> untracked-dir/
> ```
>
> instead of listing paths underneath that directory.
>
> It may also be worth noting that the real command in question was
>
> ```
> git -C untracked-dir ls-files -o --directory '*'
> ```
>
> which is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> git ls-files -o --directory 'untracked-dir/*'
> ```
>
> which behaves the same for the purposes of this issue (the '`*`' can match the empty string), but becomes relevant for the proposed fix.
>
> At first, based on the report, I decided to try to view this as a regression and tried to find a way to recover the old behavior without breaking other stuff, or at least breaking as little as possible.
> However, in the end, I couldn't figure out a way to do it that wouldn't just cause lots more problems than it solved.
>
> The old behavior was a bug:
>
> - Although older git would avoid cleaning anything with `git clean -f .git`, it would wipe out everything under that directory with `git clean -f .git/`.
>   Despite the difference in command used, this is relevant because the exact same change that fixed clean changed the behavior of ls-files.
> - Older git would report different results based solely on presence or absence of a trailing slash for `$SUBDIR` in the command `git ls-files -o --directory $SUBDIR`.
> - Older git violated the documented behavior of not recursing into directories that matched the pathspec when `--directory` was specified.
> - And, after all, [commit b9670c1f5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9670c1f5e6b98837c489a03ac0d343d30e08505) (`dir`: fix checks on common prefix directory, 2019-12-19, Git v2.25.0-rc0) didn't overlook this issue; it explicitly stated that the behavior of the command was being changed to bring it inline with the docs.
>
> (Also, if it helps, despite that commit being merged during the 2.25 series, this bug was not reported during the 2.25 cycle, nor even during most of the 2.26 cycle -- it was reported a day before 2.26 was released.
>
> So the impact of the change is at least somewhat small.)
>
> Instead of relying on a bug of `ls-files` in reporting the wrong content, change the invocation of ls-files used by git-completion to make it grab paths one depth deeper.
>
> Do this by changing '`$DIR/*`' (match `$DIR/` plus 0 or more characters) into '`$DIR/?*`' (match `$DIR/` plus 1 or more characters).
>
> Note that the '`?`' character should not be added when trying to complete a filename (e.g. '`git ls-files -o --directory merge.c?*"' would not correctly return "[`merge.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c0af173a136785b3cfad4bd414b2fb10a130760a/merge.c)" when such a file exists), so we have to make sure to add the '`?`' character only in cases where the path specified so far is a directory.

---

Warning: Git 2.29 (Q4 2020) fixes a regression introduced during 2.27 cycle.

See [commit cada730](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cada7308ade0b9a018f9c54ea3f226e2e9c39ee5) (20 Jul 2020) by [Martin Ågren (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 82fafc7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82fafc77bac9b3294b3e67bc021eeb511137c0f7), 30 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cada7308ade0b9a018f9c54ea3f226e2e9c39ee5): check pathspecs before returning `path_excluded`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Andreas Schwab</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Martin Ågren</sup>

> In [95c11ecc73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95c11ecc73f286e0a95d9591ae98f1221efe4633) ("Fix error-prone `fill_directory()` API; make it only return matches", 2020-04-01, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6eacc39b6d2508b6a7522902330c29714c99f5f2) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26)), we taught `fill_directory()`, or more specifically `treat_path()`, to check against any pathspecs so that we could simplify the callers.
>
> But in doing so, we added a slightly-too-early return for the "excluded" case. We end up not checking the pathspecs, meaning we return `path_excluded` when maybe we should return `path_none`. As a result, [`git status --ignored -- pathspec`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cada7308ade0b9a018f9c54ea3f226e2e9c39ee5/Documentation/git-status.txt#L102)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---ignoredltmodegt))</sup> might show paths that don't actually match "`pathspec`".
>
> Move the "excluded" check down to after we've checked any pathspecs.

---

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) fixes *another* regression introduced during 2.27 cycle, which can impact git-bash completion.

In a non-bare repository, the behavior of Git when the `core.worktree` configuration variable points at a directory that has a repository as its subdirectory, regressed in Git 2.27 days.

See [commit d6c9a71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6c9a717558a5ec36516026e68dcad3cbc4df1ff), [commit 2712899](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27128996b88f3dd0624324f8eb9648c0754cfa20) (16 Jun 2022) by [Goss Geppert (`ggossdev`)](https://github.com/ggossdev).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc6315e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc6315e1fc1d5c0d7afd3fe20cf192bd4c484930), 14 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`dir`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27128996b88f3dd0624324f8eb9648c0754cfa20): traverse into repository
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Goss Geppert</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Since [8d92fb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d92fb292706fd8d13cfe55353b2ec9345153a3e) ("`dir`: replace exponential algorithm with a linear one", 2020-04-01, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6eacc39b6d2508b6a7522902330c29714c99f5f2) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26)) traversing into a repository's directory tree when the traversal began outside the repository's standard location has failed because the encountered repository was identified as a nested foreign repository.
>
> Prior to this commit, the failure to traverse into a repository's default worktree location was observable from a user's perspective under either of the following conditions (there may be others):
>
> 1. Set the `core.worktree` location to a parent directory of the default worktree; or
> 2. Use the `--git_dir` option while the working directory is outside
>    the repository's default worktree location
>
> Under either of these conditions, symptoms of the failure to traverse into the repository's default worktree location include the inability to add files to the index or get a list of untracked files via `ls-files`.
>
> This commit adds a check to determine whether a nested repository that is encountered in recursing a path is actually `the_repository`.
> If so, we simply treat the directory as if it doesn't contain a nested repository.