# Why 'git ls-files' is not shown on tab completion?

Tags: git, bash

Recently I found the command

```
git ls-files
```

and I find it very useful (see the it with `-h` option). Why doesn't it appear if i type `git` and then press `Tab`?

I mean - where is the list of "other" commands of `git`?

Comment: Note: the performance of filename completion (allowed by ls-files) improves with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018): see "[Git bash-completion with filename support?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50124294/6309)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git ls-files` is a plumbing command and many of these commands are "hidden" and rightfully so. Over time, many have been added to the bash completion, but many are still "hidden"

Comment: Ok. But can You please give me a link to some list of "hidden" git commands? I'd like to check them out.

Comment: @Adobe You can see a list by running `git help -a`.  You can also override the tab-completion to show everything by adding the following to your `~/.bash_completion` file: `_completion_loader git; __git_compute_porcelain_commands() { __git_compute_all_commands; __git_porcelain_commands=$__git_all_commands; }`

Comment: This answer does not answer the question asked - 'where are the "other" commands of `git`?'. So why is it tagged as the correct answer?

Answer (score 6):

Look at your `~/.git-completion.sh` and the `__git_list_porcelain_commands()` function. The commands that git supports but won't tab-complete are listed there. Most of these commands are so-called "plumbing" commands, including `ls-files`. You can easily make them tab-completed by commenting the respective line. Like this:

```
#ls-files)         : plumbing;;
#ls-remote)        : plumbing;;
#ls-tree)          : plumbing;;
```

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), the command line completion (in `contrib/`) learned to complete pathnames for various commands better.
And that includes `git ls-files`!

See [commit 7d31407](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d314073488ae81b8f5cdecb4d00a78529fa7dc3), [commit 8b4c2e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b4c2e0b1c4ff47c07b2c1bbc937bb46e889755e) (18 May 2018), and [commit 7b00342](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b0034206843c38dc96e700a527e06b88ac35d69), [commit 193757f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/193757f8062f7b9a1e2f1137be4c6f720d74c4f0), [commit c1bc0a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1bc0a0e927265c38aa6e4cf1c9b9e7866225b68), [commit 9703797](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9703797c9d6b4d1831bf32bc0ab721a9411c716a), [commit 105c0ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/105c0efff335bc813fe7bf970fbdf1b92fc49391), [commit a364e98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a364e984d1db4dddf5ddce494ed96db437bc025e), [commit f12785a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f12785a3a735c01e0d17e21f063c21ebe8bda200), [commit 3dfe23b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3dfe23ba51664467d89ba937e607ffef6501c3f3), [commit 6bf0ced](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bf0ced4e21bfc757641ec537b8bb9dd63ece904), [commit 722e31c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/722e31c713a2f33dc483c0f17f208b2260faebe4), [commit 5bb534a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bb534a620a1e7424e80cc89c53f9e3573fba0bc) (16 Apr 2018) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4ce7218](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ce72180abe72dbb40f5e6a517deea814014e005), 30 May 2018)</sup>

> ### completion: improve handling quoted paths in '`git ls-files`'s output
>
> If any pathname contains backslash, double quote, tab, newline, or any
>   control characters, '`git ls-files`' and '`git diff-index`' will enclose
>   that pathname in double quotes and escape those special characters
>   using C-style one-character escape sequences or `\nnn` octal values.
>
> This prevents those files from being listed during git-aware path
>   completion, because due to the quoting they will never match the
>   current word to be completed.

That leads to various speed improvements:

> ### completion: remove repeated `dirnames` with '`awk`' during path completion
>
> During git-aware path completion, after all the trailing path
>   components have been removed from the output of 'git ls-files' and
>   'git diff-index', each directory name is repeated
>   as many times as the number of listed paths it contains.
>   This can be a lot of repetitions, especially when invoking path completion close
>   to the root of a big worktree.
>
> Listing all tracked files (12) and directories (23) at the top of the
>   worktree in linux.git (over 62k files), i.e. what's doing all the hard
>   work behind 'git ls-files ':
>
> Before this patch, best of five, using GNU awk on Linux:
>
> ```
> real    0m0.069s
> user    0m0.089s
> sys     0m0.026s
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> real    0m0.052s
> user    0m0.072s
> sys     0m0.014s
>
> Difference: -24.6%
> ```
>
> ### completion: let '`ls-files`' and '`diff-index`' filter matching paths
>
> During git-aware path completion, e.g. '`git rm dir/fil<TAB>`', both
>   '`git ls-files`' and '`git diff-index`' list all paths in the given '`dir/`'
>   matching certain criteria (cached, modified, untracked, etc.)
>   appropriate for the given git command, even paths whose names don't
>   begin with 'fil'.
>   This comes with a considerable performance penalty when the directory in question contains a lot of paths, but the current word can be uniquely completed or when only a handful of those paths match the current word.
>
> Reduce the number of iterations in this codepath from the number of
>   paths to the number of matching paths by specifying an appropriate
>   globbing pattern to '`git ls-files`' and '`git diff-index`' to list only
>   paths that match the current word to be completed.
>
> This speeds up path completion considerably when there are a lot of
>   non-matching paths to be filtered out.
>   Uniquely completing a tracked filename at the top of the worktree in linux.git (over 62k files), i.e. what's doing all the hard work behind 'git ls-files Mak' to complete 'Makefile':
>
> Before this patch, best of five, on Linux:
>
> ```
> $ time cur=Mak __git_complete_index_file
>
> real    0m2.159s
> user    0m1.299s
> sys     0m1.089s
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> real    0m0.033s
> user    0m0.023s
> sys     0m0.015s
>
> Difference: -98.5%
> Speedup:     65.4x
> ```
>
> ### completion: fill `COMPREPLY` directly when completing paths
>
> This speeds up path completion when there are a lot of paths matching
>   the current word to be completed.
>   In a pathological repository with 100k files in a single directory, listing all those files:
>
> Before this patch, best of five, using GNU awk on Linux:
>
> ```
> $ time cur=dir/ __git_complete_index_file
>
> real    0m0.983s
> user    0m1.004s
> sys     0m0.033s
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> real    0m0.313s
> user    0m0.341s
> sys     0m0.029s
>
> Difference: -68.2%
> Speedup:      3.1x
> ```

Comment: You don't appear to have said anything about getting e.g. `git ls-` to complete to `git ls-files`, which is what OP asked about. 5 demerits!

Answer (score -2):

In a default install, Tab completion only lists names of commands as they appear in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.  There is no file `/usr/bin/git ls-files`.

`ls-files` is a sub command that you will have to teach your shell about.  Assuming you are using bash, you can run `help complete` to see what commands you can put in your `.bashrc`.

If your distribution supplies the bash-completion package, you can install it to save a lot of time:

```
apt-get install bash-completion  # on Debian/Ubuntu/etc.
yum install bash-completion      # on Fedora/Red Hat/etc.
```

But as manojlds points out, this won't work for the less commonly used git commands such as `ls-files` because bash-completion hides those from you.  You would have to edit `/etc/bash_completion.d/git` to change that.

Comment: I'm pretty certain OP has bash-completion installed and it's still no good.