# automatic Suggestions for Checking out/seeing diffs for files modified

Tags: git, bash, git-diff, git-bash

I have a big project, in which while working on any feature, I could be making edits to 6-8 files, each in turn nested some 6-10 levels. (Currently I copy paste the whole filepath using `ctrl+shift+c, ctrl+shift+v`, but it can get frustrating when there are spaces in the filepath)

When I do a `git diff <filename>`, or a `git checkout <filename>` for reviewing/removing my changes, is there a way I can get suggestions for the filenames which have been modified?

Some feature or hack? Something like `git diff` -> `tab` displaying me a list of options *from files modified*.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/6034472/236871 possible duplicate?

Comment: @KurzedMetal Thanks! trying out the link now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh-My-ZSH provides a plugin that tab-autocompletes tracked file paths (i.e. in the index).

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/gitfast/git-completion.bash